# Layout using div tags

Tags: html, css

I'm not good at making layouts and designs for a page, but I've been trying for about 2 hours now on how to make this kind of layout using div tags. It looks like the header and body is split in half while the footer is just a small bar at the bottom. Can anyone give my ideas on doing this?

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=css+grid+boilerplate

Comment: What layout are you trying to achieve? Can you share your html so we can see what you have done so far?

Comment: Checkout frameworks like [960.gs](http://960.gs/) or Bootstrap

Comment: "how to make this kind of layout" might need to give a bit more info there

Comment: It would be better if you could share some code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

The following html code is 2 columns simple layout. I think this is what you are looking for.

```
            <!doctype html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <title>This is simple css layout using divs.</title>
                <style>
                    *{
                        margin: 0;
                        padding: 0;
                    }

                    .header{
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 40px;
                        background-color: #aaaaaa;
                        padding: 10px;
                    }

                    .contain{
                        padding: 15px;
                    }

                    .leftContain{
                        width: 49%;
                        height: 300px;
                        background-color: green;
                        float: left;
                    }

                    .rightContain{
                        width: 49%;
                        height: 300px;
                        background-color: blue;
                        float: right;
                    }

                    p{
                        padding: 10px;
                    }

                    .footer{
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 40px;
                        background-color: #aaaaaa;
                        padding: 10px;
                    }

                    .clear{
                        clear: both;
                    }

                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div class="container">

                    <div class="header">
                        <h4>Menu</h4>
                    </div>  <!-- end of header-->

                    <div class="contain">

                        <div class="leftContain">
                            <p>division 1</p>
                        </div>  <!-- end of leftContain -->

                        <div class="rightContain">
                            <p>division 2</p>
                        </div>  <!-- end of rightContain -->

                        <div class="clear"></div>

                    </div>  <!-- end of contain -->


                    <div class="footer">
                        <h4>footer</h4>
                    </div>  <!-- end of footer -->

                </div>  <!-- end of container -->
            </body>
            </html>
```